# Как мне поступить с таблицами в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

в БД есть три таблицы: 
1) студент (там есть колонка-семья, где пишется один из двух значении из другой таблицы)
2) семья (вот это та таблица где есть два значения, "полная" или "неполная" )
3) статус семьи (тут статус семьи, например "без отца", "без матери", "родители разведены" и т.д.)
**Мне надо чтобы в 1 таблицы в колонке семья были значении типа "Полная родители разведены " или "Неполная без матери и без отца" или "Неполная без отца", нечто в это роде**

Comment: Кривая схема данных порождает невменяемые желания. Лучше переделайте, если ещё не поздно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вам подойдет одна таблица со значениями

```
students(family{полная;неполная},status{without_father;withour_mother;parents_divorced})
```

Если надо две и более то нужно делать связи таблиц по полю

Comment: ОО спс) блин долго ломал голову :), спс еще раз!